# CardView inside RecyclerView not resizing to correct height when expanded

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder

After creating a RecyclerView, I've noticed that my CardView does not resize to the correct height when I expand it (**Item A**, **Item B** and **Item C**). It should be the same height as the txtSubtitle TextView. I think that `txtSubtitleHeight` could be the culprit but does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to resolve it?

[image]

```
public class MyFragmentRV extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public int mGridViewHeight;
//    public int txtSubtitleHeight;
    private static final int ITEM_TYPE = 100;
    private static final int HEADER_TYPE = 101;
    private static final int HEADER_TYPE_2 = 102;
    private static final int GRID_TYPE = 103;
//    GridView mGridViewA;
    ValueAnimator mAnimatorGV, mAnimatorTV;
    TextView txtArrowGV, txtTitle;

    //
    static final String[] frenchVowels = new String[]{
            "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"
    };

    public MyFragmentRV.MyAdapter adapterGV;

    public MyFragmentRV() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);

        // set the linear layout manager
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        // SpannableStrings
        // dynamically change SpannableString colour using defined attribute
        int[] attrS = {R.attr.spannablestringtextColor};
        TypedArray ta = getActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrS);
        int colorSS = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK); //Color.BLACK - default value (colour will change automatically depending on chosen theme)
        Log.d(TAG, "clickMethod 1) " + Integer.toHexString(colorSS));
        ta.recycle();


        // SpannableString (start)
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        SpannableString str1 = new SpannableString(" Item A ");
        str1.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yellow)), 0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssb.append(str1);

        SpannableString str2 = new SpannableString(" Hello World");
        str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorSS), 0, str2.length(), 0);
        ssb.append(str2);
        // SpannableString (end)

        // init data
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(ssb);
        data.add("Item B");
        data.add("Item C");

        subdata = new ArrayList<>();
        subdata.add("\u2022 a");
        subdata.add("\u2022 b\n\u2022 bb");
        subdata.add("\u2022 c\n\u2022 cc\n\u2022 ccc");

        adapter = createAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<CharSequence> data;
    ArrayList<String> subdata;
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> adapter;


    // creates the adapter
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> createAdapter() {
        return new RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case HEADER_TYPE:
                        return new ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.header, parent));

                    case HEADER_TYPE_2:
                        return new ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.header, parent));

                    case ITEM_TYPE:
                        return new ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.recyclerview_item_tv, parent));

                    case GRID_TYPE:
                        return new ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.recyclerview_item_gv, parent));

                    default:
                        return new ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.recyclerview_item_tv, parent));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
                final Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(getContext(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME); // FontManager class must be accessed first before text views can be set as image views

                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case HEADER_TYPE:
                        Button expandButton = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                        expandButton.setText("Expand all");

                        expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            }
                        });
                    break;
                    case HEADER_TYPE_2:
                        Button collapseButton = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                        collapseButton.setText("Collapse all");

                        collapseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            }
                        });
                    break;
                    case ITEM_TYPE:
                        // get the current item
                        CharSequence itemA = data.get(position - 3);
                        String itemB = subdata.get(position - 3);


                        txtTitle = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tv_A);
                        txtTitle.setText(itemA);

                        final TextView txtSubtitle = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tv_B);
                        txtSubtitle.setText(itemB);
                        txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        //Add onPreDrawListener
                        txtSubtitle.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                                txtSubtitle.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                                txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                                final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                                txtSubtitle.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                                txtSubtitleHeight = txtSubtitle.getMeasuredHeight();

                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        final TextView txtArrowTV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tv_expandcollapse);
                        txtArrowTV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);
                        txtArrowTV.setTypeface(iconFont);

                        //
                        CardView cardView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_tv);
                        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutTV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_tv_titlerow);

                        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
//                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CardView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if(txtSubtitle.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                } else {
                                    collapseTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        mLinearLayoutTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(txtSubtitle.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                } else {
                                    collapseTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        txtArrowTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(txtSubtitle.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                } else {
                                    collapseTV(txtSubtitle, txtArrowTV);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    break;
                    case GRID_TYPE:
                        TextView titleG = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gv_A);

                        titleG.setText("French vowels");

                        final TextView txtArrowGV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gv_expandcollapse);
                        txtArrowGV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);
                        txtArrowGV.setTypeface(iconFont);

                        final GridView mGridViewA = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.gv);
                        mGridViewA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mGridViewA.setEnabled(false);
                        mGridViewA.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                        adapterGV = new MyFragmentRV.MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0);
                        mGridViewA.setAdapter(adapterGV);
                        for (String frenchVowel : frenchVowels) {
                            adapterGV.addAdapterItem(new MyFragmentRV.AdapterItem(frenchVowel));
                        }


                        //Add onPreDrawListener
                        mGridViewA.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                                mGridViewA.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                                mGridViewA.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                                final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                                mGridViewA.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                                mGridViewHeight = mGridViewA.getMeasuredHeight();

                                return true;
                            }
                        });


                        CardView cardViewG = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_gv);
                        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutGV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_gv_titlerow);

                        cardViewG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(mGridViewA.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandGV(mGridViewA);
                                } else {
                                    collapseGV(mGridViewA);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        mLinearLayoutGV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(mGridViewA.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandGV(mGridViewA);
                                } else {
                                    collapseGV(mGridViewA);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        txtArrowGV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(mGridViewA.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                                    expandGV(mGridViewA);
                                } else {
                                    collapseGV(mGridViewA);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return data.size() + 3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return HEADER_TYPE;
                    case 1:
                        return HEADER_TYPE_2;
                    case 2:
                        return GRID_TYPE;
                    default: return ITEM_TYPE;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private View inflateHelper(int resId, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(resId, parent, false);
    }

    // inner class for viewholder to use,
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public void expandGV(final GridView mGridViewA) {
        mGridViewA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtArrowGV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

       ValueAnimator mAnimatorGV = slideAnimator(0, mGridViewHeight, mGridViewA);
        mAnimatorGV.start();
    }
    public void collapseGV(final GridView mGridViewA) {
        txtArrowGV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);

        int finalGVHeight = mGridViewA.getHeight();

        mAnimatorGV = slideAnimator(finalGVHeight, 0, mGridViewA);

        mAnimatorGV.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                mGridViewA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimatorGV.start();
    }
    public void expandTV(final TextView txtSubtitle, final TextView txtArrowTV) {
        txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        txtArrowTV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

        mAnimatorTV = slideAnimator(0, txtSubtitleHeight, txtSubtitle);

        mAnimatorTV.start();
    }

    public void collapseTV(final TextView txtSubtitle, final TextView txtArrowTV) {
        txtArrowTV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_down);

        int finalTVHeight = txtSubtitle.getHeight();

        mAnimatorTV = slideAnimator(finalTVHeight, 0, txtSubtitle);

        mAnimatorTV.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimatorTV.start();
    }


    public ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View txtSubtitle) {

        final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                // update height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsTV = txtSubtitle.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParamsTV.height = value;
                txtSubtitle.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTV);

//                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsGV = mGridViewA.getLayoutParams();
//                layoutParamsGV.height = value;
//                mGridViewA.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsGV);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/cv_tv"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardview_tv_titlerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_tv_A"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_tv_expandcollapse"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout_tv"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_tv_B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Macmist's suggestion**

[image]

Comment: Didnt get your question

Comment: ok You dont want any extra space when there is only 1 category

Comment: upload xml also, i think you are using math_parent for hight

Comment: @FaizMir that's correct. See my attached GIF image in the question. I don't want any extra blank space below the **txtSubtitle** TextView when the CardView is expanded.

Comment: you have a txtSubtitleHeight variable, but in your onPreDraw() method you are also declaring a variable with the same name and returning without even using it, is that on purpose? If you don't assign the value to something outside the scope of the onPreDraw method it will be lost, maybe that is related to your problem

Comment: @Hamza I'm not. See my XML

Comment: @Macmist should that variable have a different name? What should the value be assigned to?

Comment: @Macmist the problem that you found was not done on purpose. Do I need to assign that value to the public variable?

Comment: @MacaronLover yes if you want to be able to access that value from somewhere else than the onPreDraw function you will have to :)

Comment: @Macmist I changed `final int txtSubtitleHeight = txtSubtitle.getMeasuredHeight();` to `txtSubtitleHeight = txtSubtitle.getMeasuredHeight();` and `txtSubtitleHeight` changed to purple but still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @MacaronLover If I understand correctly, this txSubtitleHeight is the height you want to give to your views right? Have you tried, instead of calculating it to, set it to a hardcodedvalue? To see whether it's the resizing or the function that calculated the size that is not working as expected

Comment: @Macmist Not yet, because the height of that TextView will always be different (as demonstrated in the screenshot).

Comment: @MacaronLover Yes I understand that, here I suggested that just to determine if when fixing txtSubtitleHeight to a hardcoded value, your cardview will actually be set to that height or not. If yes, it means there is a problem when calcutating the height, if not, this is the way you assign the height that is not working.

Comment: @Macmist okay, I can try it out. Do you know how to set `txtSubtitleHeight` to a hard coded value?

Comment: @MacaronLover yes it just means initialize it with a value of your choice, something like `public int txtSubtitleHeight = 200;` then make sure to comment every other occurence of `txtSubtitleHeight = something` in your code so it doesnt change

Comment: @Macmist I have just tried it out and when expanded, each CardView resizes to exactly 200 in height.

Comment: @Macmist where would I go from here?

Comment: @SD826E Hi, I have a similar use case.  Did the answer below solve your problem?  If not, did you out the issue and what was the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it seems that it's your function to get the height that is not correct.
Actually By rereading your code, I think I might have found an idea of what is going on. With the tests you have done we've determined that the issue was on the side of the function that retrieve the size. Now, on your demonstrating gif, all the expanded views have the same size, and for the last card, it seems to have the size you want, which is not having any space after the text.

So based on those information, my guess is the following:

- your function to determine the height actually works
- BUT you have only one variable defining that size (txtSubtitleHeight)
- So for each card, the height is calculated and txtSubtitleHeight is replaced by the height of that card
- And in the end, txtSubtitleHeight has the height of the last card seen. And as you are using this variable for expanding each card, each card will have the height from that last card seen.

So, based on that, if I'm not mistaken, a simple fix would be to have one height variable for each card, so one for each viewholder from your adapter.

You could do like:

```
   // inner class for viewholder to use,
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
        int height;
    }
```

then you can update your onPreDraw function like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    txtSubtitle.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                                txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                                txtSubtitle.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    viewHolder.height = txtSubtitle.getMeasuredHeight();
    return true;
}
```

And finally in your expandTV

```
public void expandTV(final TextView txtSubtitle, final TextView txtArrowTV, final ViewHolder holder) {
    txtSubtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    txtArrowTV.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);

    mAnimatorTV = slideAnimator(0, holder.height, txtSubtitle);

    mAnimatorTV.start();
}
```

And I believe it should solve your issue :)